# Error while trying to call a wcf service

Tags: c#, .net, iis, tcp, windows-server-2012

I'm trying to connect to a WCF service on a server.

I've set up a Site in the IIS on the server and set the `Enabled Protocols` to `http,net.tcp`.
Additionally, I configured the `Site Bindings` like this:

- http > Port: 80 > IP Address: *
- net.tcp > Binding Information: 808.*

Under `Authentication`, I've enabled `Anonymous Authentication` and `Windows Authentication`.

The services `Net.Tcp Listener Adapter` and  `Net.Tcp Port Sharing Service` are running too.

When I call the webservice with a browser (via `http`), everything works and I can list the `wsdl` etc.

But when trying to connect via `tcp`, I get the following error:

> Error: Cannot obtain Metadata from net.tcp://myserver/MyService.svc If this is a Windows (R) Communication Foundation service to which you have access, please check that you have enabled metadata publishing at the specified address.  For help enabling metadata publishing, please refer to the MSDN documentation at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=65455.WS-Metadata Exchange Error    URI: net.tcp://myserver/MyService.svc    Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'net.tcp://myserver/MyService.svc'.    Could not connect to net.tcp://myserver/MyService.svc. The connection attempt lasted for a time span of 00:00:21.0010999. TCP error code 10060: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 10.x.yyy.zz:808.     A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 10.x.yyy.zz:808

- Are there any other things I have to make sure to be able to connect via `tcp`?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you do TELNET 10.x.yyy.zz 808 to check if you can reach the server on port 808? 10060 is connect timeout. Your request is not reaching IIS as far as I can tell.

Comment: I've tried to connect with telnet but I'm getting the message "Could not open connection to the host, on port 808: Connect failed"

Comment: Ok then your server is not listening on that port or your firewall is blocking your request. Can you try enabling WCF non-activation endpoints under Windows features / .NET Framework 3.5 on the server? This will require a restart I am afraid.. At least you can check whether it is enabled or not.

Comment: Note: You can also issue netstat -a on the server to see if port 808 is being listened or not.

Comment: äll .NET Framework 3.5 and 4.5 Features are installed (including Non-HTTP-Activation and WCF Services). I'm trying to check if I can issue a netstat -a command

Comment: I'm getting a record `TCP [::]:808 myServer:0 LISTENING` when issueing a netstat -a

Comment: Then can you repeat the telnet command on the server with IP 127.0.0.1? If this succeeds it is a firewall issue on your client

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94171/discussion-between-oguz-ozgul-and-xeraphim).

Comment: unfortunately, the stackoverflow-chat is blocked in our organisation :( i could successfully connect via telnet 127.0.0.1 808... so does this mean that the port 808 is not open?

Comment: This means the server is OK, but you cannot access it. You should first check your client computer's firewall and allow outbound connections to port 808. If you still can't connect (telnet 10.x.yyy.zz 808) that means a company firewall between your client computer and the server is blocking your request

Comment: Would you let me know the result and may be upvote if that was the issue? That would be very kind of you. Thanks.

Comment: I've been looking at the "Inbound Rules" on the server and saw that the `Windows Communication Foundation Net.TCP Listener Adapter (TCP-In)`-Rule is enabled. I couldn't find a similar "Outbound Rule" on the clients computer :(

Comment: If the rule is not there, it is by default blocked. You should define the outbound rule to allow outbound tcp connections on port 808. I don't know your company's security policies, it could be the client fireall or a hardware firewall on the network but this certainly seems like a network issue (client computer cannot access server on port 808)

Comment: ok thanks could you add this as answer so I can accept it? :) thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a network issue since 10060 means connect timeout.

1. Check the server firewall and make sure that Windows Communication Foundation Net.TCP Listener Adapter (TCP-In) rule is enabled.
2. Check the client computer's firewall and add make sure an outbound rule allowing tcp connections on port 808
3. If you still can't connect, a network firewall device might be blocking the request

Answer (score 0):

I think that you may need to turn metadata exchange on:
[The following explains one way to do it.](http://jeffbarnes.net/blog/post/2006/10/16/metadata-exchange-endpoint.aspx)